# Headless eclipse managed by Jenkins to run OSGi application server

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, osgi, integration-testing, headless

we would like to adapt our Jenkins CI roundtrip as it takes to long (late feedback).

The current flow looks like described below:

- OSGi server bundles are checked out and build with ant.
- the OSGi bundles are packaged to be used on linux distros.
- a server is set up to install the above packages and to run HTTP interface tests (integration tests) against it.

We would like to get rid of creating the linux packages and to install a server with these packages as this consumes most of the time.

Instead we would like to execute the existing tests against a headless eclipse which is running the server (based on compiled jars or imported projects if possible) managed by Jenkins CI.

Now some questions:

- Is it possible to run a headless eclipse within Jenkins (I think so as it is just executing a java application)?
- Is it possible (and does it makes sense) to have an eclipse instance permanently running and to get used from more than one job? So we have to only update the jars/imported projects that have been changed ... or
- do we have to extract eclipse and set it up each test run?
- Is it possible to import projects within the headless eclipse or do we have to throw compiled jars into its installation?
- Are there any other ways to get HTTP interface tests executed against a running server we are currently not thinking about?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you use PDE Build/Ant for building? Do you use the HttpService for deploying the HTTP interface? Did you check if you could enhance your Ant build with a target that launches the tests and server?

Comment: We have a custom build based on ant. The services are deployed as Servlets via the HttpService.
But the current build result are bundles packaged within linux packages and not only the bundles.